# 'Description' in the Google Calendar API [Python]

Tags: python

I'm using that command: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

I'm trying to print 'description' field. I can print 'summary', 'start', etc, but when i type:

```
print (event['description'])
```

i've got an error:

```
print (event['description'])
KeyError: 'description'
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you print `event`?

Comment: Just looks like there is no description... You could check if there is one before attempting to print it to avoid the error.

Comment: There is a description (:. 'event' i've got a "  u'description': u'My Desc', " so there is something :D

Answer (score 1):

For some reason there is not a 'description' on the dict/json. You can avoid the error use the method .get of Dict class

> print event.get('description', 'no description')

Notice that the second parameter is the value you want to return in case that the key does not exist.